# Using QWebPage via socks

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm confused a bit on usage of QWebPage via socks using httplib2 (http/socks5/socks4).
Is there any issues or workaround on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyQt: how to use QWebPage with an anonimous proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423013/pyqt-how-to-use-qwebpage-with-an-anonimous-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Problem seem to be solved using QNetworkAccessManager 
`QNetworkAccessManager.proxyAuthenticationRequired(proxy, authenticator)`

- proxy – QNetworkProxy
- authenticator – QAuthenticator

Comment: Hope this may be useful if you want to add support on proxy servers in your applications.